# Is it possible to record only a part of screen using Game Bar screen recording of Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, recording

I have been trying to record a part of screen in my windows 10 machine. I found that Windows 10 offers a built in tool called Game bar (shortcut: Win + G), which can be used to capture screen or record video.

However, I could not find any control to record part of the screen. If I start recording, it captures the whole screen. I use similar recording in Mac where you can select a part of screen and only that part will be recorded (Shift+Cmd+5).
I did google for a while with no decisive answer anywhere.

Is it possible to do so in windows?

Comment: Game Bar does not support the feature you describe.  You will have to use a third-party solution to achieve your goal.

Comment: The product feature is incorrectly named sadly, which means alternatives, like OBS, Camtasia, Democreator (Wondershare) , Flashback Express. Others do exist.